# AWS sam build failing but npm install is successful

Tags: node.js, xslt, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Im using SAM CLI to build my nodejs project, when I add `xslt4node` in package json standalone node :`npm install` is successful but `sam build` is failing with below error.

> Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.

> Building codeuri: /home/ec2-user/xslt-transform runtime: nodejs14.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ['XsltTransformFunction']

> Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack

> Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile

> Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource

> Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall

> Build Failed

> Error: NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall - NPM Failed: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path /home/ec2-user/xslt-transform/.aws sam/build/XsltTransformFunction/node_modules/java

> npm ERR! command failednpm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuildnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Pythonnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configurationnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "/usr/lib64/python2.7"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "/usr/lib64/python2.7" is not in PATH or produced an errornpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHONnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be usednpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an errornpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be usednpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is "/usr/bin/python"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is "2.7.18"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is 2.7.18 - should be >=3.6.0npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTEDnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Pythonnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHONnpm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python

Answer (score 0):

It wants the python version to be 3.6 or higher.